# How to do two way databinding on a specific item in an array where the array index is determined dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a Javascript dynamic array coming from a database:

```
customers = [{'id':1, 'name':'John'},{'id':2, 'name':'Tim}, ...]
```

and inputs:

```
<input type='text' name="forJohnOnly" ng-model="customers[0].name" />

<input type='text' name="forTimOnly" ng-model="customers[1].name" />
```

The array comes from the database sorted and John is always the first item. While this works, I don't like it because someone might change the sort order in the database without updating the UI and the first input now holds Tim's name which is wrong. This same array is sent back to the backend to be saved in the database.

I am trying to do something like below where the correct index is determined dynamically, without creating an additional array for that purpose and copying between the two arrays

```
<input type='text' name="forJohnOnly" ng-model="customers[where customers.id=1].name" />
<input type='text' name="forTimOnly" ng-model="customers[where customers.id=2].name" />  (need to use id because name can be updated)
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**
While the data is in an array, the text boxes are not in a uniform layout such as a grid.

Comment: You can use ng-repeat

Comment: I can't use it. These are inputs already in the UI and they don't repeat like a grid or are in a uniform layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function which receive an id and return the object. Something like this

```
function getRow(id) {
    customers.forEach(itm => if(itm.id == id){ return itm; });
}
```

And use it in html like

```
<input type='text' name="forJohnOnly" ng-model="getRow(customer.id).name" />
```

Or using a `ng-repeat` like this

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <input type='text' name="{{customer.name}}Only" ng-model="customer.name" />
</div>
```

And just sort `customers` array in order you want!